# Как работает ссылка в Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

```
if($user['cat'] == 0){      
  // Проверяем наличие категории
  $mesto_cat = DB::$the->query("SELECT mesto FROM `sel_category` WHERE `mesto` = '".$message."' ");
  $mesto_cat = $mesto_cat->fetchAll();

  if (count($mesto_cat) != 0) 
    {
      $chat = escapeshellarg($chat);    
      $message = escapeshellarg($message);  
      exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid php ./select_cat.php '.$chat.' '.$message.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
      exit;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в при `/sity1` проверялась есть ли категория?
Сейчас это работает если самому нажать цифру 1. А как сделать, чтобы работало при `/sity1`?

Comment: А причём тут Телеграм? Вы кстати продумали, что случится, если $message окажется равным `"qwe'; DROP TABLE sel_category; --"`

Comment: Только учусь, как это можно исправить?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь абсолютно ошибочное суждение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#/city#USi', '', $m);
```